# Change default timeout

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have the following implementation. And the default timeout is 100 seconds.

I wonder how can I able to change the default timeout?

**HttpService.cs**

```
public class HttpService : IHttpService
{

   private static async Task GoRequestAsync<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, HttpMethod method,
        Action<T> successAction, Action<Exception> errorAction = null, string body = "")
        where T : class
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()))
        {

        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Are you doing a http call inside of your `ServiceCall` using `HttpClient`?

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r I have just updated question. Is it good enough?

Comment: Does `ServiceDataAsync` make a http call using `HttpClient`?

Comment: The reason I ask is that the default timeout of [HttpClient is 100 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=xamarinandroid-7.1#Remarks)

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r, I have added further.

Comment: You can always decrease the timeout when creating the task

Comment: @Dolev, I want to increase to 5 minutes. I need to know how I can change it

Comment: In your `AbstractHttpCommand` class are you using `HttpClient`?

Comment: I have added `AbstractHttpCommand.cs` as well.

Comment: We seem to be going deep down the rabbit hole, but I think we are getting there, what does your `IHttpService` implementation look like, does it have an `HttpClient`? Do you just want to change the timeout for this one particular request, or all your request?

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r, I have added `IHttpCommand.cs` as well. I want to change all.

Comment: `IHttpService` implementation ?

Comment: I have added that one as well.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't create HttpClient instance in 'using block' even though it is IDisposable. You should keep one HttpClient object for all your requests and dispose it at the end of application lifetime or when you know that you will not need more requests. Creating new HttpClient for every request will lead you to troubles when you will make requests frequently.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The default timeout of an `HttpClient` is [100 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=xamarinandroid-7.1#Remarks).

---

**HttpClient Timeout**

You can adjust to your `HttpClient` and set a custom timeout duration inside of your `HttpService`.

`httpClient.Timeout = 5000;`

---

**HttpClient Request Timeout**

You could alternatively define a timeout via a cancellation token [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=xamarinandroid-7.1)

```
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)))
{
    await httpClient.GetAsync(url, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

---

**A few notes:**

1. Making changes inside of the `HttpClient` will affect all requests. If you want to make it per request you will need to pass through your desired timeout duration as a parameter.
2. Passing an instance of `CancellationTokenSource` will work if it's timeout is lower than `Timeout` set by the `HttpClient` and `HttpClient`'s timeout is not infinite. Otherwise, the `HttpClient`'s timeout will take place.

Comment: What would be the side effect if I increase from 100 seconds to 10 minutes? any drawback?

Comment: Only a longer timeout period. You could also set the timeout to `httpClient.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;` if you do not want the request to timeout at all.

Comment: I can set as `client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,500);` , then what is the use of `CancellationTokenSource` ?

Comment: @stom The `CancellationTokenSource` would allow you to cancel the request prior to the timeout being triggered. The example would be if a user navigates away and you no longer need the requested data. You can then cancel the request.

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r , Good example :) Appreciate.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this ` If you want to make it per request you will need to pass through your desired timeout duration as a parameter.` how do we do this?

Comment: What if I set timeout on HttpClient from HttpClient pool? Is timeout setup reset once the call is completed and HttpClient is returned into the pool?

Answer (score 33):

`client.Timeout = 5*1000;` doesnt work because `client.Timeout` expects something of type: `System.TimeSpan`

I changed the Timeout value using:

```
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // Timeout value is 10 seconds
```

You can use other methods as well:

- [FromDays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromdays?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_FromDays_System_Double_)
- [FromHours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromhours?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_FromHours_System_Double_)
- [FromMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.frommilliseconds?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_FromMilliseconds_System_Double_)
- [FromMinutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromminutes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_FromMinutes_System_Double_)
- [FromSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_FromSeconds_System_Double_)
- [FromTicks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromticks?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_FromTicks_System_Int64_)

Just for FYI:

Default value of `Timeout` property is 100 seconds

Comment: Hi what is the max Timeout Value for this case?

Comment: @toha it seems the max value can be set to InfiniteTimeSpan. Please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2):

Since we don't see any task created with a timeout i cannot help.

But if you are using a [System.Net.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(v=vs.110).aspx) under the hood of your application than MSDN says:

> The default value is 100,000 milliseconds (100 seconds).

You can than change the value of the [HttpClient.Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) property

```
clent.Timeout = 5*1000;
```