# Http client check if server is available

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm trying to connect from a http client but if server is down for some reason I'm getting an exception while sending the request.

```
 string Send = "Request";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.1.15:8282/", new StringContent(Send, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                MessageBox.Show(content);
            }
        }
```

Is there any method to check if server is not down. Also how can I set server connection timeout, Send request timeout and receive answer timeout?

Comment: How about using try catch for exception handling?

Comment: Ok i will do that. I just wonder if it has something similar with tcp client TcpClient client = new TcpClient();


            if (client.ConnectAsync(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO).Wait(2000))
No Problem i will use try-catch.Also does it have Request or Receive timeout?

Comment: You can write multiple catches depending on exception type, or if it doesn't matter you can write just one and it will catch all unhandled exceptions :)

Comment: Thank you for answers what about timeouts?

Comment: Chcek this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155951/change-default-timeout