# The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing on adding logs to Log Analytics

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, azure-log-analytics

I have the following code to add logs to log analytics:

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = MakeClient();

private static HttpClient MakeClient()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Log-Type", "ApplicationLog");
    return client;
}
```

On running this, I get the below exception:

> The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing. The operation was canceled. The operation was canceled. The read operation failed, see inner exception. Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'SslStream'.

on this line:

```cs
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(
    CreateRequest(HttpMethod.Post, url, scheme, parameter, dateString, serializedMessage, contentType));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the inner exception?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot make Polly Timeout Policy override the HttpClient default timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473924/cannot-make-polly-timeout-policy-override-the-httpclient-default-timeout)

Answer (score 2):

HttpClient has a default timeout of 100 sec. You can set the value based on your requirements.

```
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

[For refrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to resolve this without specifying a default timeout value?

Comment: You'll have to give a value to it if you don't want it to time out in 100 seconds.

Comment: You can check this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155951/change-default-timeout

Comment: Depends on how do you want the application to behave. Can you give more details on that?